# After applying location, origin not at 0,0,0

Tags: 3d-view, transforms, origin

Noticed this thing, wondering if its a bug of new blender(2.83.1).

After applying location (or all transforms for that matter) objects origin is not at the grid center, nor 3d cursor. Its fixable by just setting origin to cursor, but that's an extra step.

Here's a screenshot with all transforms applied and mirror modifier.

[image]

Comment: It could be that the object is parented to another object.

Comment: I am wondering the same

Answer (score 0):

I am not actually sure about the technicalities yet, but it can be solved by clearing the object's properties. Select the object, then go `Object > Clear > Origin`. You can also clear Location, Scale and Rotation if needed.

Alternatively (or in addition), if the object has a parent, you can go `Object > Parent > Clear Parent Inverse` or `Clear And Keep Transformation` depending on if you want to preserve parenting (first case) or remove the object from the parent.

Found it here
https://blenderartists.org/t/apply-location-sets-objects-origin-to-perent-origin-0-0-0/606188/5